# I get an error even though no changes was made to my project. "Attempt to access invalid address"

Tags: python, pygame

I have a pygame project that crashes whenever I call `pygame.mixer.music.load('./sounds/background music.mp3')`.

It was working perfectly fine yesterday, please note that I have made no changes to the code.

Any advice would be appreciated as I have tried everything that I could think of to fix this issue.

I checked my pygame folder and there does exist a "libmpg123.dll" file.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/ngtaw/PycharmProjects/snakeversus/snakeversus.py", line 291, in 
>       pygame.mixer.music.load('./sounds/background music.mp3')
>   pygame.error: Failed loading libmpg123.dll: Attempt to access invalid address.

Comment: The error message is a little vague... what happens if you try to open a different music file? Is that path valid for both the location of the source file and the location from which you are calling?

Comment: The same error appears when trying to open a different mp3 file. The path to the source file and `'./sounds/background music.mp3'` should be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this by updating pygame from pygame 1.9.6 to pygame 2.0.0.dev6.